# Metabox Data Isn't Saving

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, metadata

I created a metabox within a class. I needed it for a custom post type that I had. The metabox is displaying fine, but the values refuse to save. I've altered the code several times, but it still isn't working for me. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Here is the full code:

```
<?php 
class portfolio_metabox {

    public function __construct() {
        if ( is_admin() ) {
            add_action( 'load-post.php', array( $this, 'init_metabox' ) );
            add_action( 'load-post-new.php', array( $this, 'init_metabox' ) );
        }
    }

    public function init_metabox() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_metabox' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_metabox' ), 10, 2 );

    }

    public function add_metabox() {
        add_meta_box(
            'details',
            __( 'Project Details', 'chic' ),
            array( $this, 'render_project_metabox' ),
            'portfolio',
            'advanced',
            'default'
        );
    }

    public function render_project_metabox( $post ) {
        // Retrieve an existing value from the database.
        $portfolio_web_design  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'portfolio_web_design ', true );
        $portfolio_web_dev  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'portfolio_web_dev ', true );
        $portfolio_digital_art  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'portfolio_digital_art ', true );
        $portfolio_graphic_design  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'portfolio_graphic_design ', true );

        // Set default values.

        // Form fields.
        echo '<table class="form-table">';

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th><label for="portfolio_project" class="portfolio_project_label">' . __( 'Project Type', 'chic' ) . '</label></th>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="portfolio_web_design " class="portfolio_project_field" value="' . $portfolio_web_design  . '" ' . checked( $portfolio_web_design , 'checked', false ) . '> ' . __( ' Web Design', 'chic' ) . '</label><br>';
        echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="portfolio_web_dev " class="portfolio_project_field" value="' . $portfolio_web_dev  . '" ' . checked( $portfolio_web_dev , 'checked', false ) . '> ' . __( ' Web Development', 'chic' ) . '</label><br>';
        echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="portfolio_digital_art " class="portfolio_project_field" value="' . $portfolio_digital_art  . '" ' . checked( $portfolio_digital_art , 'checked', false ) . '> ' . __( ' Digital Art', 'chic' ) . '</label><br>';
        echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="portfolio_graphic_design " class="portfolio_project_field" value="' . $portfolio_graphic_design  . '" ' . checked( $portfolio_graphic_design , 'checked', false ) . '> ' . __( ' Graphic Design', 'chic' ) . '</label><br>';
        echo '<p class="description">' . __( 'Project Type', 'chic' ) . '</p>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';

    }

    public function save_metabox( $post_id, $post ) {

        // Sanitize user input.
        $portfolio_new_web_design = isset( $_POST[ 'portfolio_web_design' ] ) ? 'checked' : '';
        $portfolio_new_web_dev = isset( $_POST[ 'portfolio_web_dev' ] ) ? 'checked' : '';
        $portfolio_new_digital_art = isset( $_POST[ 'portfolio_digital_art' ] ) ? 'checked' : '';
        $portfolio_new_digital_art = isset( $_POST[ 'portfolio_graphic_design' ] ) ? 'checked' : '';

        // Update the meta field in the database.
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'portfolio_web_design ', $portfolio_new_web_design  );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'portfolio_web_dev ', $portfolio_new_web_dev  );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'portfolio_digital_art ', $portfolio_new_digital_art  );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'portfolio_graphic_design ', $portfolio_new_digital_art  );

    }

}

new portfolio_metabox;

?>
```

UPDATE:

The code given by Mukesh Panchal worked great. It saves just like I wanted it to, but I still can't get the metadata to display on the template. Any ideas why that's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try below updated code:

```
<?php
class portfolio_metabox {

    public function __construct() {
        if ( is_admin() ) {
            add_action( 'load-post.php',     array( $this, 'init_metabox' ) );
            add_action( 'load-post-new.php', array( $this, 'init_metabox' ) );
        }
    }
    public function init_metabox() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes',        array( $this, 'add_metabox' )         );
        add_action( 'save_post',             array( $this, 'save_metabox' ), 10, 2 );
    }

    public function add_metabox() {
        add_meta_box(
            'details',
            __( 'Project Details', 'chic' ),
            array( $this, 'render_project_metabox' ),
            'portfolio',
            'advanced',
            'default'
        );
    }

    public function render_project_metabox( $post ) {

        // Retrieve an existing value from the database.
        $portfolio_web_design  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'portfolio_web_design ', true );
        $portfolio_web_dev  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'portfolio_web_dev ', true );
        $portfolio_digital_art  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'portfolio_digital_art ', true );
        $portfolio_graphic_design  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'portfolio_graphic_design ', true );

        // Set default values.
        // Form fields.
        echo '<table class="form-table">';
        echo '  <tr>';
        echo '      <th><label for="portfolio_project" class="portfolio_project_label">' . __( 'Project Type', 'chic' ) . '</label></th>';
        echo '      <td>';
        echo '          <label><input type="checkbox" name="portfolio_web_design" class="portfolio_project_field" value="' . $portfolio_web_design  . '" ' . checked( $portfolio_web_design , 'checked', false ) . '> ' . __( ' Web Design', 'chic' ) . '</label><br>';
        echo '          <label><input type="checkbox" name="portfolio_web_dev" class="portfolio_project_field" value="' . $portfolio_web_dev  . '" ' . checked( $portfolio_web_dev , 'checked', false ) . '> ' . __( ' Web Development', 'chic' ) . '</label><br>';
        echo '          <label><input type="checkbox" name="portfolio_digital_art" class="portfolio_project_field" value="' . $portfolio_digital_art  . '" ' . checked( $portfolio_digital_art , 'checked', false ) . '> ' . __( ' Digital Art', 'chic' ) . '</label><br>';
        echo '          <label><input type="checkbox" name="portfolio_graphic_design" class="portfolio_project_field" value="' . $portfolio_graphic_design  . '" ' . checked( $portfolio_graphic_design , 'checked', false ) . '> ' . __( ' Graphic Design', 'chic' ) . '</label><br>';
        echo '          <p class="description">' . __( 'Project Type', 'chic' ) . '</p>';
        echo '      </td>';
        echo '  </tr>';
        echo '</table>';

    }

    public function save_metabox( $post_id, $post ) {

        // Sanitize user input.
        $portfolio_new_web_design = isset( $_POST[ 'portfolio_web_design' ] ) ? 'checked' : '';
        $portfolio_new_web_dev = isset( $_POST[ 'portfolio_web_dev' ] ) ? 'checked' : '';
        $portfolio_new_digital_art = isset( $_POST[ 'portfolio_digital_art' ] ) ? 'checked' : '';
        $portfolio_new_digital_art = isset( $_POST[ 'portfolio_graphic_design' ] ) ? 'checked' : '';

        // Update the meta field in the database.
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'portfolio_web_design', $portfolio_new_web_design  );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'portfolio_web_dev', $portfolio_new_web_dev  );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'portfolio_digital_art', $portfolio_new_digital_art  );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'portfolio_graphic_design', $portfolio_new_digital_art  );
    }
}
new portfolio_metabox;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a extra space in your input name="" attributes, like here:

```
name="portfolio_web_design "
```

This should be:

```
name="portfolio_web_design"
```

After that your isset should work properly ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
class portfolio_metabox {

    public function __construct() {

        if ( is_admin() ) {
            add_action( 'load-post.php', array( $this, 'init_metabox' ) );
            add_action( 'load-post-new.php', array( $this, 'init_metabox' ) );
        }

    }

    public function init_metabox() {

        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_metabox' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_metabox' ), 10, 2 );

    }

    public function add_metabox() {

        add_meta_box(
            'details',
            __( 'Project Details', 'chic' ),
            array( $this, 'render_project_metabox' ),
            'portfolio',
            'advanced',
            'default'
        );

    }

    public function render_project_metabox( $post ) {
        // Retrieve an existing value from the database.
        $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );

                $portfolio_web_design = ( isset($post_meta['portfolio_web_design'][0]) && $post_meta['portfolio_web_design'][0] != '' ) ? $post_meta['portfolio_web_design'][0] : 0;
                $portfolio_web_dev = ( isset($post_meta['portfolio_web_dev'][0]) && $post_meta['portfolio_web_dev'][0]!= '' ) ? $post_meta['portfolio_web_dev'][0] : 0;
                $portfolio_digital_art = ( isset($post_meta['portfolio_digital_art'][0]) && $post_meta['portfolio_digital_art'][0]!= '' ) ? $post_meta['portfolio_digital_art'][0] : 0;
                $portfolio_graphic_design = ( isset($post_meta['portfolio_graphic_design'][0]) && $post_meta['portfolio_graphic_design'][0]!= '' ) ? $post_meta['portfolio_graphic_design'][0] : 0;
        // Set default values.

        // Form fields.
        ?>
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="portfolio_project" class="portfolio_project_label"><?php esc_html_e( 'Project Type', 'chic' ) ?></label;></th>
                <td>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="portfolio_web_design" class="portfolio_project_field" value="1" <?php checked( $portfolio_web_design , 1 ) ?>> <?php esc_html_e( ' Web Design', 'chic' ); ?></label><br>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="portfolio_web_dev" class="portfolio_project_field" value="1" <?php checked( $portfolio_web_dev , 1 ) ?>> <?php esc_html_e( ' Web Development', 'chic' ); ?></label><br>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="portfolio_digital_art" class="portfolio_project_field" value="1" <?php checked( $portfolio_digital_art , 1 ) ?>> <?php esc_html_e( ' Digital Art', 'chic' ); ?></label><br>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="portfolio_graphic_design" class="portfolio_project_field" value="1" <?php checked( $portfolio_graphic_design , 1 ) ?>> <?php esc_html_e( ' Graphic Design', 'chic' ); ?></label><br>
                    <p class="description"><?php esc_html_e( 'Project Type', 'chic' ) ?></p;>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php
    }

    public function save_metabox( ) {
        global $post;
        // Sanitize user input.
        $portfolio_new_web_design = ( isset( $_POST['portfolio_web_design'] ) && $_POST['portfolio_web_design'] == 1 ) ? 1 : 0;
        $portfolio_new_web_dev = ( isset( $_POST['portfolio_web_dev'] ) && $_POST['portfolio_web_dev'] == 1 ) ? 1 : 0;
        $portfolio_new_digital_art = ( isset( $_POST['portfolio_digital_art'] ) && $_POST['portfolio_digital_art'] == 1 ) ? 1 : 0;
        $portfolio_new_digital_art = ( isset( $_POST['portfolio_graphic_design'] ) && $_POST['portfolio_graphic_design'] == 1 ) ? 1 : 0;

        // Update the meta field in the database.
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'portfolio_web_design', $portfolio_new_web_design );
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'portfolio_web_dev', $portfolio_new_web_dev );
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'portfolio_digital_art', $portfolio_new_digital_art );
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'portfolio_graphic_design', $portfolio_new_digital_art );

    }

}

new portfolio_metabox;
```

I cleaned up your code a bit. Try not to put space after everything, it's not necessary. The problem was in the way you're pulling the post meta out. The variables like `$portfolio_web_design` were empty.

I tested this and it worked.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: "Notice: Undefined index: portfolio_web_design in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/chic/portfolio_meta.php on line 37"

Comment: It says that for all of them.

Comment: I've edited the code a bit (added a check), should be working now.